# make vendor/phone_defconfig won´t work, generated .config does not have some stuff. Why?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel, gnu-make

On https://github.com/MoonBase-Project/MSM-4.19-MiBengal/ I had to do

```
make CONFIG_HAVE_KVM=y CONFIG_KVM=y CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST=y O=out ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- vendor/citrus-perf_defconfig
make CONFIG_HAVE_KVM=y CONFIG_KVM=y CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST=y O=out ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- -j$(nproc --all) 2>&1 | tee kernel.log
```

because putting

```
CONFIG_HAVE_KVM=y 
CONFIG_KVM=y 
CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST=y
```

on `vendor/citrus-perf_defconfig` wouldn't work no matter what I tried. The `.config` generated from it wouldn't have the KVM configs.

What is happening? I went as far as looking at the [C code](https://github.com/MoonBase-Project/MSM-4.19-MiBengal/blob/mibengal-r/scripts/kconfig/conf.c#L493) that generates it, but I couldn't understand what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also add the following line to `arch/arm64/configs/vendor/citrus-perf_defconfig`:

```
CONFIG_VIRTUALIZATION=y
```

As you can see in `arch/arm64/kvm/Kconfig`, KVM options are inside an `if` block:

```
if VIRTUALIZATION

config KVM
        bool "Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM) support"
...
endif # VIRTUALIZATION
```